# How to remove the whitespace while concatenating while some have Null values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the name of the players where some of the players have no middle name. While concatenating as below I am getting an white space for players without a middle name and logic holds good for players with a middle name. How do I remove the unwanted whitespace for NULL valued columns alone?

I want only the Initial of the middle name in the concatenate expression.

```
SELECT m_playerid, first_name + ' ' + SUBSTRING (coalesce (middle_
name, ' '), 1,1) + ' ' + last_name as [Full name]
, game as Game, inns as Innings, [scores] as Scores FROM  odsports
```

> Shouldn't I be introducing a condition to get remove of the
>   whitespace for NULL? I am struck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that concatenating a `NULL` to anything with the `+` operator produces a `NULL` whereas the `CONCAT` function converts `NULL` to empty string.

So `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', LEFT(middle_name,1) + ' ', last_name)` will handle null middle names as you want -  as in the following example

```
WITH T(first_name, middle_name, last_name) AS
(
SELECT 'Franklin', 'Delano', 'Roosevelt' union all
SELECT 'Barack', NULL, 'Obama'
)
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', LEFT(middle_name,1) + ' ', last_name)
FROM T
```

Returns

```
+----------------------+
|   (No column name)   |
+----------------------+
| Franklin D Roosevelt |
| Barack Obama         |
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a replace for double spaces, as well as use isnull function. Try this

```
SELECT 
m_playerid, 
REPLACE(
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(first_name ,'')))
+CASE WHEN middle_name IS NULL
        THEN ' '
    ELSE ' '+LEFT(ISNULL(middle_name,' '),1)+' ' END
+
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(last_name,'')))
,'  ',' ') as [Full name],
game as Game, 
inns as Innings, 
[scores] as Scores 
FROM  odsports
```

Comment: the extra whitespace still exists!!! we need only 1 whitespace between each part of the name. thanks for suggesting a condition for NULL values for the last name, in our case the first name and last name can't be null.

Comment: @C82 Then it is possible that there are trailing spaces on first name and last name. I've updated the answer, try that

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ISDATE'.  

@Martin Smith answer solves it. It's lean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  m_playerid,
    COALESCE(first_name + ' ' + middle_name + ' ' + last_name,
             first_name + ' ' + last_name,
             first_name,
             last_name) as [Full name],
    game as Game, 
    inns as Innings, 
    [scores] as Scores
FROM odsports
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   m_playerid, 
   LTRIM(CONCAT(first_name,Space(1),LTRIM(RTRIM(middle_name+space(1)+last_name)))) 
                                                                         as [Full name],
   game as Game,
   inns as Innings, 
   [scores] as Scores 
FROM  odsports
```

Comment: it gives only the first name for players with null middle names.

Comment: Have you executed query? Even first name is null  its removes white spaces

Comment: Yes, I did! But still the same. @Martin Smith answer solves it.